# php Put contents of a file into an array and then split each string of this array into a seperate array

Tags: php, arrays

this is probably a ridiculous question to ask but i am learning php so please help if you can.

I have a file called 'res_example.txt' and it looks like this:

```
>chr1:2198584545754_genome_1000+ 511 66 (+) nan full_model
>chr2:2198581212154_genome_1000+ 649 70 (+) nan full_model
>chr3:2115151215754_genome_1000+ 666 80 (+) nan full_model
>chr4:2198584545754_genome_1000+ 750 90 (+) nan full_model
>chr5:1218455145754_genome_1000+ 800 100 (+) nan full_model
>chr6:1231354645454_genome_1000+ 850 110 (+) nan full_model
>chr7:1231213211134_genome_1000+ 900 120 (+) nan full_model
```

I want to open this file. Put each line into an array $resArray, so each line is a separate string.
so it will be like this:

```
$resArray= array(' >chr1:2198584545754_genome_1000+ 511 66 (+) nan full_model',  '>chr2:2198581212154_genome_1000+ 649 70 (+) nan full_model')
```

etc

Then with Each key from $resArray, I want to create another Array $ArrayResults exploding each string at each space in the string.  This will ow me to work with each part of each string separately.

I hope this ,made sense. I probably didn't ask the question in the right way, so Apologies.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to open this file. Put each line into an array

[`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

> with Each key from $resArray, I want to create another Array $ArrayResults exploding each string at each space in the string

[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

So it'll become something like this:

```
$resArray = file('res_example.txt');
$resSplit = array();

foreach ($resArray as $res)
{
    $resSplit[] = explode(' ', $res);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This really improves me knowledge of file handling.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the contents of your file, and put them in the variable `contents`.

```
$f = fopen('filename.txt', 'r+');
$contents = fread($f, filesize("filename.txt"));
fclose($f);
```

Next, split the content on the newline character `\n` (or `\r\n` if you're on a Windows machine).

```
$resArray = explode("\n",$contents);
```

And finally, loop through the array to split each value on the space character.

```
foreach($resArray as $r) {
   $ArrayResults[] = explode(" ",$r);
}
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at explode(), you can find it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Cheers.